# Local deploy of Google cloud function fails with "javap -cp: Class not found"

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, deployment, google-cloud-functions

Using STS my cloud function works fine locally using the below command:

`mvn function:run -Drun.functionTarget=functions.Gcpfunc`

However, when doing a local Source or pre-packaged Lite JAR deployment, the build logs on GCP show error at the below stage:

```
"builder": Running "javap -classpath sts2gcphttpfunc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar functions.Gcpfunc" 
"builder": Error: class not found: functions.Gcpfunc.
```

However, if I create a function directly on GCP and deploy the same, the above line shows success in the logs.

My System specs: Java 8, Maven 3.6.3, Windows 8.1
Attachments: Screenshots of pom.xml, build log error of "Source" and "JAR" deployment

Command for source deploy:

```
gcloud functions deploy Gcpfunction3 --region=us-east1 --entry-point=functions.Gcpfunc --runtime=java11 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated
```

Command for Lite JAR deployment:

```
gcloud functions deploy Gcpfunction3 --region=us-east1 --entry-point=functions.Gcpfunc --runtime=java11 --trigger-http --source=target/deployment --allow-unauthenticated
```

[POM.xml Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu0zN.png)
[image: BuildLog-function deploy from GCP]
[image: BuildLog-function deploy from localsystem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved. Had to remove *Spring-boot-maven-plugin* from *pom.xml* so that Class files are not created in *Boot-inf* folder

Answer (score 0):

When you take a look in the [example](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/first-java#specifying_dependencies) from google documentation syntax of local test is:

```
mvn function:run -Drun.functionTarget=your.package.yourFunction
```

But in the [gcloud deploy command example](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/java-deploy#deploy_from_source) from documentation sytax is:

```
gcloud functions deploy NAME --entry-point NAME --runtime RUNTIME TRIGGER [FLAGS...]
```

So please notice that `--entry-point` in `gcloud` command is should contain class name while in `mvn function:run` command it's with package. I think this is main problem, so verify this value. Exact infomation how to use it you may find [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/filesystem#deploy_using_the_gcloud_tool).

One more, honestly not sure if important, is that you are using java 8 in maven, while in GCF you can use only java 11, and actually you are using it in the `gcloud` command.

Comment: thanks for the response.I've looked at the Google docs and ran the command as you've suggested,and still get same error.Google docs do indicate "--entry-name" can be _classname_(if class has no package) or _fully-qualified name_(package.class).I've re-attached images of 2 Buildlogs in original post highlighting how the javap command is executed differently in the 2 cases,(1)deploy on GCP (2)deploy from local-system.I understand for javap command to execute it needs the path to the extracted JAR file, which is not indicated in (2)command whilst indicated in(1).Appreciate help to resolve